# Explain this sed command?

Tags: shell, sed

```
sed //x.18
```

This supposedly deletes the first 18 characters of a line. This seems to be highly classified information and cannot be found anywhere on the internet, but what does a forward slash mean in the sed command? What does the x mean?

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "//x.18": extra characters at the end of x command`

Comment: My teacher told us to use this command and it does not work for me as well. I'm trying to figure out what he meant to write.

Comment: No idea; that's pretty far from any `sed` syntax. `//` will match on every line, and `x` would swap with hold space; `.18` is as out of place as a giraffe in Tokyo Metro. To delete first 18 characters, you could use `sed 's/^.\{0,18\}//'` or `cut -c19-`.

Comment: @alvits Where did your read that `x`command is not supported on Linux?...

Comment: This is the explanation of x command: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-53 But this command still doesn't work. So there's nothing to explain.

Comment: @Amadan I like the giraffe in Tokyo Metro :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a typo or a cruel trick. `cut -c 19-` is what you want.